# Obtaining type information after ToolBox.parse?

Tags: scala, reflection, abstract-syntax-tree

How can I find the type of (a subtree of) a Tree returned from ToolBox.parse?

For example, given a source file Test.scala containing the following:

```
val a = 7                   // exp1
val b = 12.0                // exp2
var c = "hello"             // exp3
val d = someFn( 9 )         // exp4
```

I'd like to be able to query the types of exp1-4 in from `tree' the following:

```
val sourceCode = io.Source.fromFile( "Test.scala" ).mkString
val tree = toolBox.parse( sourceCode )
```

I understand how to use Traverser to visit tree nodes: the question concerns how to find the *type* of a Tree obtained in this fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to call `toolbox.typeCheck` on the tree returned from `toolbox.parse`.

Comment: thanks, but it's not clear to me how this would help, since (for example), doing showRaw() on the tree corresponding to 
  val a = 7
evaluates as:
  ValDef(Modifiers(), newTermName("a"), TypeTree(), Literal(Constant(7)))
for both the original and typechecked tree...

Comment: `showRaw` prints the string representation of the tree, but nothing about types and symbols.

Comment: Try showRaw(tree, printIds = true, printTypes = true)

Answer (score 1):

The tree returned from `parse` doesn't contain type information, you need to use `typecheck` afterwards:

```
object ToolBoxTest extends App {

  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.runtimeMirror
  import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

  val tb = runtimeMirror(getClass().getClassLoader()).mkToolBox()
  import tb._, u._

  val tree = typecheck(parse("""
    val a = 7                   // exp1
    val b = 12.0                // exp2
    var c = "hello"             // exp3
  """))

  new Traverser() {
    override def traverse(t: Tree) = {
      t match {
        case v: ValDef =>
          println(v.tpt)
        case t =>
          super.traverse(t)
      }
    }
  }.traverse(tree)
}
```

This prints

```
Int
Double
String
```